# Spark MLib - Create LabeledPoint from RDD[Vector] features and RDD[Vector] label

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classification, apache-spark-mllib

I am building a training set using two text files representing documents and labels.

**Documents.txt**

```
hello world
hello mars
```

**Labels.txt**

```
0
1
```

I have read in these files and converted my document data to a `tf-idf` weighted `term-document matrix` which is represented as a `RDD[Vector]`. I have also read-in and created a `RDD[Vector]` for my labels:

```
val docs: RDD[Seq[String]] = sc.textFile("Documents.txt").map(_.split(" ").toSeq)
val labs: RDD[Vector] = sc.textFile("Labels.txt")
  .map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble)))

val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
val tf: RDD[Vector] = hashingTF.transform(docs)
tf.cache()

val idf = new IDF(minDocFreq = 3).fit(tf)
val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)
```

I would like to use `tfidf` and `labs`to create a `RDD[LabeledPoint]`, but I am not sure how to apply a mapping with two different `RDDs`. Is this even possible/efficient, or do I need to rethink my approach?

Comment: You should `join` both `RDD`s.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I was considering that approach, but how can I do this if neither `RDD` has `keys` to `join` by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this is to `join` based on indices:

```
import org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner

// Add indices
val idfIndexed = idf.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
val labelsIndexed = labels.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)

// Create range partitioner on larger RDD
val partitioner = new RangePartitioner(idfIndexed.partitions.size, idfIndexed)

// Join with custom partitioner
labelsIndexed.join(idfIndexed, partitioner).values
```